# Proving some identities in partial differential calculus

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $u,w$ be some arbitrary coordinates in some 2D coordinate system and $p,q$ represent some arbitrary coordinates in another 2D coordinate system. How do we prove the identities,

$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial p}+\frac{\partial p}{\partial w}\frac{\partial w}{\partial p}=1$$
$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial q}+\frac{\partial p}{\partial w}\frac{\partial w}{\partial q}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial q}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial p}+\frac{\partial q}{\partial w}\frac{\partial w}{\partial p}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial q}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial q}+\frac{\partial q}{\partial w}\frac{\partial w}{\partial q}=1$$

PS: These identities are briefly mentioned in Thomas A Moore's book titled A General Relativity Workbook under Chapter 5 named Arbitrary Coordinate Systems. However no proof is given for the same. Can someone please help me with the proofs?

Answer (score 0):

It's just the (standard) fact that the Jacobian matrix for an invertible map $(u,v) \mapsto (p,q)$ is the inverse matrix of the Jacobian matrix for the inverse map $(p,q) \mapsto (u,v)$. Which follows from the chain rule, if you differentiate the composition of the map and its inverse.